Langchain4J - AnthropicChatModel - Issues with Custom Base URL based API calls - "Required Authorization Header Missing"
I am trying to use Langchain4J to connect to Open AI models and Anthropic model that are hosted behind my organization's base URL. The OpenAI Model is working fine. However, the Anthropic Model always throws the error "Required Authorization Header is missing". Below is the code snippet of both the model testing that I did.
//THIS code works fine without any issues
import dev.langchain4j.model.chat.ChatLanguageModel;
import dev.langchain4j.model.openai.OpenAiChatModel;
import dev.langchain4j.model.output.Response;
import dev.langchain4j.model.chat.ChatMessage;
import dev.langchain4j.model.input.Prompt;

public class OpenAIChatExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String clientId = "myclientid";
        String clientId = "myclientsecret";
        
        TokenAuthenticator authenticator = new TokenAuthenticator(clientId, clientSecret);

        
        ChatLanguageModel model = OpenAiChatModel.builder()
                .baseUrl("https://mycustombaseurl")
                .apiKey(authenticator.getValidToken())
                .modelName("gpt-4o") 
                .build();

        try {
            
            String response = model.generate("What is LLM?");
            System.out.println("Simple Response: " + response);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }    
}

//THIS code fails with the error "Required Authorization header is missing"
import dev.langchain4j.model.chat.ChatLanguageModel;
import dev.langchain4j.model.anthropic.AnthropicChatModel;
import dev.langchain4j.model.output.Response;
import dev.langchain4j.model.chat.ChatMessage;
import dev.langchain4j.model.input.Prompt;

public class AnthropicChatExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String clientId = "myclientid";
        String clientSecret = "myclientsecret";
        
        TokenAuthenticator authenticator = new TokenAuthenticator(clientId, clientSecret);

        
        AnthropicChatModel model = AnthropicChatModel.builder()
                .baseUrl("https://mycustombaseurl")
                .apiKey(authenticator.getValidToken())
                .modelName("claude-3-5-sonnet") 
                .build();

        try {
            
            String response = model.generate("What is LLM?");
            System.out.println("Simple Response: " + response);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }    
}

Below is the error message I get for the failing code snippet above (AnthropicChatExample)
Caused by: dev.langchain4j.model.anthropic.internal.client.AnthropicHttpException: {"Error": "Required Authorization header is missing"}

I tried running the above examples using the below Langchain4j versions that can be found in my build.gradle file below, the java version I am using in Java 21.
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.10.0')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    implementation 'dev.langchain4j:langchain4j:0.36.2'
    implementation 'dev.langchain4j:langchain4j-core:0.36.2'
    implementation 'dev.langchain4j:langchain4j-open-ai:0.36.2'
    implementation group: 'dev.langchain4j', name: 'langchain4j-anthropic', version: '0.36.2'
    implementation 'dev.langchain4j:langchain4j-embeddings-all-minilm-l6-v2:0.36.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:5.2.1'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.2'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}



Please let me know if I am missing something here.

For some reason, the default AnthropicChatModel is something I could not use for my use case. Actually, we needed an Authorization Header as a Bearer Token for my api endpoint which is different from the endpoint that AnthropicChatModel was using, so I had to come up with a customized version of the ChatModel implementation that aligns with my API request and response structure, which is given below.
package com.langchain4j.poc;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import dev.langchain4j.data.message.AiMessage;
import dev.langchain4j.data.message.ChatMessage;
import dev.langchain4j.data.message.SystemMessage;
import dev.langchain4j.data.message.UserMessage;
import dev.langchain4j.model.chat.ChatLanguageModel;
import dev.langchain4j.model.output.Response;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CustomAnthropicChatModel implements ChatLanguageModel {
    private final OkHttpClient client;
    private final String baseUrl;
    private final String apiKey;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private final String modelName;

    public CustomAnthropicChatModel(String baseUrl, String apiKey, String modelName) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
        this.modelName = modelName;

        this.client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(chain -> {
                    Request original = chain.request();
                    Request modified = original.newBuilder()
                            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiKey)
                            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                            .build();
                    return chain.proceed(modified);
                })
                .build();

        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public Response<AiMessage> generate(List<ChatMessage> messages) {
        try {
            Map<String, Object> requestBody = new HashMap<>();
            requestBody.put("model", modelName);
            requestBody.put("messages", convertMessages(messages));

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(baseUrl + "/chat/completions")
                    .post(RequestBody.create(
                            objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestBody),
                            MediaType.parse("application/json")
                    ))
                    .build();

            try (okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("API call failed: " + response.code() + " " + response.message());
                }

                String responseBody = response.body().string();
                Map<String, Object> responseMap = objectMapper.readValue(responseBody, Map.class);

                String content = extractContentFromResponse(responseMap);
                AiMessage aiMessage = AiMessage.from(content);

                return Response.from(aiMessage);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to generate response", e);
        }
    }

    private List<Map<String, Object>> convertMessages(List<ChatMessage> messages) {
        return messages.stream()
                .map(msg -> {
                    Map<String, Object> converted = new HashMap<>();
                    converted.put("role", convertRole(msg));
                    converted.put("content", msg.text());
                    return converted;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private String convertRole(ChatMessage message) {
        if (message instanceof UserMessage) return "user";
        if (message instanceof AiMessage) return "assistant";
        if (message instanceof SystemMessage) return "system";
        return "user";
    }

    private String extractContentFromResponse(Map<String, Object> response) {
        try {
            List<Map<String, Object>> choices = (List<Map<String, Object>>) response.get("choices");

            Map<String, Object> firstChoice = choices.get(0);

            Map<String, Object> message = (Map<String, Object>) firstChoice.get("message");

            return (String) message.get("content");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to parse response structure: " + response, e);
        }
    }

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private String baseUrl;
        private String apiKey;
        private String modelName;

        public Builder baseUrl(String baseUrl) {
            this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder apiKey(String apiKey) {
            this.apiKey = apiKey;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder modelName(String modelName) {
            this.modelName = modelName;
            return this;
        }

        public CustomAnthropicChatModel build() {
            return new CustomAnthropicChatModel(baseUrl, apiKey, modelName);
        }
    }
}


and with this, if I update my AnthroipicChatExample like below, things are working fine,
//THIS code works fine
import dev.langchain4j.model.chat.ChatLanguageModel;
import dev.langchain4j.model.anthropic.AnthropicChatModel;
import dev.langchain4j.model.output.Response;
import dev.langchain4j.model.chat.ChatMessage;
import dev.langchain4j.model.input.Prompt;

public class AnthropicChatExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String clientId = "myclientid";
        String clientSecret = "myclientsecret";
        
        TokenAuthenticator authenticator = new TokenAuthenticator(clientId, clientSecret);

        
        CustomAnthropicChatModel model = CustomAnthropicChatModel.builder()
                .baseUrl("https://mycustombaseurl")
                .apiKey(authenticator.getValidToken())
                .modelName("claude-3-5-sonnet") 
                .build();

        try {
            
            String response = model.generate("What is LLM?");
            System.out.println("Simple Response: " + response);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }    
}


